# Hyperlink in a textbox

Tags: asp.net

I have an Asp.Net webform.I want to add a hyperlink in a textbox at run time. I mean if some particular text is entered then show hyperlink. How I can achieve this

Any suggestions.

Dee

Answer (score 4):

A HTML Textbox **cannot** contain anything else than text.

If you want a textbox to contain HTML elements like links, look up a [**Rich textbox**](http://www.google.dk/search?q=asp.net%20richtextbox) / [**WYSIWYG editor**](http://www.google.dk/search?q=asp.net%20wysiwyg).

Comment: I cannot use Rich textbox in my application.

Comment: Can you tell me why you cannot use a Rich textbox in your application?